# Align Label and Icon in same line

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular2-mdl

I want to show text follwed by an icon.
I'm using material icons.

[image]

I want to achieve what it is on the left. But the right side is the one I'm getting.

I tried padding,margin,line height and everything but I couldn't make them align.

The Working webpage for the above issue is [here](https://ob.deepanartist.com/main/tour-packages)

Html

```
                <div class="package-rating-detail">
                    <label>{{package.rating}}</label>
                    <mdl-icon class="mdl-color-text--orange">star_rate</mdl-icon>
                </div>
```

css

```
.package-rating-detail {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

So how can I align the label and the icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `flex`:

```
.package-rating-detail[_ngcontent-c3] {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0.3em; // cosmetic
    margin-left: 1em; // cosmetic
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can improve the alignment and make it look better by adding some space between the star and the label:

```
.package-rating-detail[_ngcontent-c3] > label {
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}
```

(the `margin-top` will take the label a bit down, which looks better in my opinion).

[image]